# Expected type-specifier before ';' token

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I get the error "Expected type-specifier before ';' token" in a line of code marked below. Is it asking to specify the type of (*this)? Why wouldn't the compiler know the type of (*this)?

```
struct P{
};

struct R : public P{
  virtual P* copy(){
    return new(R(*this));  //error here
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to say: `return new R(*this);` That's the form of the non-placement `new`-expression. No extra parentheses.